# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I using Tomcat 8.0.26 and during the deploy (after executing ./startup) I am getting the following exception:

> 28-Mar-2018 15:07:58.926 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   ie.company.web.AppContextListener  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.(Ejb3Configuration.java:142)
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
>           at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
>           at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
>           at ie.company.persistence.PersistenceUtil.resetFactory(PersistenceUtil.java:44)
>           at ie.company.persistence.PersistenceUtil.createEntityManager(PersistenceUtil.java:37)
>           at ie.company.persistence.repository.impl.MerchantCategoryRepositoryImpl.findAllMerchantCategories(MerchantCategoryRepositoryImpl.java:38)
>           at ie.company.persistence.repository.impl.RepositoryImpl.findAllMerchantCategories(RepositoryImpl.java:1204)
>           at ie.company.web.AppContextListener.initStrutsApplicationContext(AppContextListener.java:113)
>           at ie.company.web.AppContextListener.contextInitialized(AppContextListener.java:86)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I've seen dozens of posts about this exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Objec

But no one does make sense to me, since I have the same “.war” file running on different servers (I don't have any problems running the application on my local system in Eclipse as well). Currently the application is running on Linux Opensuse and I am migrating it to Linux Ubuntu 16.04. I don't think that I am missing any library because I copied and pasted the exactly Tomcat installation from the old server on which the applications is currently running. Any clue? Please help me.

Comment: compare tomcat lib/ext jars with working tomcat lib/ext jars with versions.

Comment: As I said I have the same installation(I crtl + c, crtl + v, the Tomcat folder 
from the old server). Did you get it? Thanks for helping.

Comment: post your hibernate configuration file

Comment: Do you mean the persistence.xml?

Comment: application.conf

Comment: I dont have this file :(

Comment: Check you pom.xml, maybe logging artifact has <scope>provided</scope>

Comment: Well, thank you, but I don't think that it does make sense because the same .war file is working on different servers.